# Checking what element in the list has the string I am searching for

Tags: python, list, element

I have a list, I want to check whether the string "Monday" is in it, but I want to know, if it is then what element of the list is it in?

```
    list1 = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
if "Monday" in list1:
    print("True")
```

Comment: Does it matter if the search term is in the list more than once?

Comment: No it doesn't, I'm actually trying the methods suggested in a tuple as well, using list1.index does not work when list1 is a tuple

Comment: @Coder77 `list1.index("Monday")` does work if `list1` is a tuple,

Answer (score 4):

```
list1 = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
if "Monday" in list1:
    print(list1.index("Monday"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `enumerate()` function as such:

```
for i, j in enumerate(["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]):
    if j == 'Monday':
        print i
```

This will give you the index location of the variable "Monday," in this instance, wherever in the list the item is - taking into account that it might be listed in multiple locations.

Answer (score 0):

If we are searching for "b":

`[x for x,y in enumerate(["a","b","b","c","d","e","f","g"]) if "b" in y]`

Will account for multiple appearances and give the indexes of all of them as a list

the above returns as: `[1, 2]`